# How to stop redraw in my vimrc

Tags: vim, redraw

I want to map `F12` to get tags by `ctags`, so I wrote in my `vimrc` like this:

```
map <F12> :call Do_CsTag()<CR>
function Do_CsTag()
  if(executable('ctags'))
    silent! execute "!ctags -R --c-types=+p --fields=+S *"
  endif
endf
```

When I press `F12` in my `C` source file, the screen turn to be white, how could I fix it?

Comment: what does "screen turn to be write" mean?

Comment: the vim screen changes to white.

Comment: does pressing `<C-l>` fix it?

Comment: I tryed Zyx's answer, It did work, but think you the same.

Comment: @znlyj You will notice a difference on slow terminals (like ssh to remote server). `<C-l>`/`:redraw!` redraws the scrapped screen completely producing a flash and is more generic way to handle this. `system()` does not let the screen to be scrapped, but it won’t work for programs that require to be launched in a terminal and does not work well with strings containing newline. Neither is true for your ctags call thus it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `system()` in this case: replace

```
silent! execute "!ctags -R --c-types=+p --fields=+S *"
```

with

```
call system('ctags -R --c-types=+p --fields=+S *')
```

.